# Create a file in a specific folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a code which creates a sheet containing a file on a daily basis, but the file is going to the root folder and I am willing the file to be created in a specific already existing folder. Below is the code.

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")  
  var foldername = 'Absense';
  var folderlisting = 'List of ' + foldername + ' ' +date;

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );

  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the Drive API. Since there is no "move" option, you have to make a copy and delete the new one:

1. Generate the new Spreadsheet and get the Id
2. Get the Id of the destination folder
3. Copy the file in the folder
4. Delete the original file

Example:

```
    var sheet_id = SpreadsheetApp.create("testSprsheet").getId();

    Drive.Files.copy({"parents":[{"id":"destination folder ID"}]}, sheet_id);
    Drive.Files.remove(sheet_id);
```

More information [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy).